# Сортировка вставками

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, java

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть не отсортированный массив. Например:

```
0, 5, 4, 2
```

С начала я прохожу циклом

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < arr.length; i++)
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > arr[j]; j--)
```

Если условие выполняется я нахожу позицию для вставки элемента, с помощью бинарного поиска . Мне необходимо с помощью `arraycopy` произвести перестановку элементов.

Comment: ну и вопрос?

Comment: умею только Arrays.sort(arr); =) ток не кому не говори

Comment: Переставлять элементы при помощи arraycopy не хочешь ты, юный падаван. Силой оператора присваивания и временной переменной воспользуйся. (И да пребудет с тобою Сила!)

Comment: А в чем проблема?

    public static void arraycopy(Object src,
                             int srcPos,
                             Object dest,
                             int destPos,
                             int length)

[описано здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Там же:

    If the src and dest arguments refer to the same array object, then the copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array ...

Только это неэффективно ... 

(как всегда в комменте мало места)

Comment: Я это читал , просто не могу применить на своем примере . Не могу правильно подобрать индексы . Если нужно менять два рядом стоящих элемента , то все вроде в порядке , а вот если необходимо менять какие то произвольные элементы , то параметры уже другие .

Comment: А Вы чуть измените структуру кода

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > arr[j]; j--);
        if (i > j) {
           int t = arr[i]; 
           // тут надо сдвигать на 1 элемент, начиная с arr[j+1]
           arr[j] = t;
        }
     }

Видите, временная переменная все равно нужна. Поэтому скажите своему преподавателю, 

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int j, t = arr[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > arr[j]; j--)
           arr[j] = arr[j-1];
        arr[j] = t;
    }

что так будет красивей.

Comment: Ну, заведите вспомогательный массив вместо временной переменной, вместо копирования делайте `arraycopy` с `length == 1`. Скажите преподавателю, что он знатный извращенец, и пожелайте, чтоб он сам пользовался таким кодом, каким предлагает писать.

Comment: Если рассматривать пример, то получается следующее. Я иду по внутреннему циклу for и сравниваю с начала числа 0 и 5 
0 > 5
Нет, значит иду дальше.
5 > 4
Да, значит ищу место для 4 методом бинарного поиска. Нахожу для него место под индексов в массиве "1" . Вот теперь и состоит главная проблема. Не получается реализовать перестановку элементов методов arraycopy. Потому что , если я решил проблему с рядом стоящими элементами, то массив преобразуется так,
0, 4, 5, 2 
А здесь нужно поставить 2 между "0" и "4". Тут уже нужно по другому использовать индексы в arraycopy или так , как я не понимаю.

Comment: А, понятно. Ну отлично, делайте так:

1. запомните 2 во временную переменную
2. сдвиньте 4, 5 на одну позицию вправо при помощи `arraycopy`, получится 0, 4 (старое значение), 4, 5
3. запишите 2, которое вы запомнили, на место старой 4, получится 0, 2, 4, 5.

Беру свои слова назад, задание имеет смысл.

Comment: Скажите , а как придумать общую формулу, потому что это вы сказали для конкретного примера ? Как определить на сколько позиций когда сдвигать , ведь массив может быть другого размера? С направлением сдвига понятно - вправо.

Comment: @Drylozav, прочитав про бинарный поиск в вопросе, я сначала подумал, что это просто описка. Судя по комментарию - нет.

На самом деле, после внутреннего цикла **никакой** поиск уже **не нужен**. Переменная **`j`** после внутреннего цикла уже содержит индекс элемента массива, в который надо переместить arr[i]!!!

Другими словами, внутренний цикл это как раз тот самый поиск (правда линейный). Он может быть совмещен (как в примере 2) с копированием, а может и нет. Тогда после него нужен arraycopy.

В принципе, *вместо* внутреннего цикла можно делать бинарный поиск (ищем j),  а потом arraycopy.

Comment: Это понятно , я не могу понять , какие индексы нужно вставить в метод arraycopy. То есть такие , что б подходил для перестановки любых элементов в массиве

Comment: arraycopy(arr, j+1, arr, j+2, i-j-1);